# Proxy server with authentication in node.js

Tags: node.js, proxy, http-proxy

I want to create a proxy server that filters websites based on a user's basic auth token and to be able to get a quota of how much internet they used.

I found a couple of packages on NPM (http-proxy, proxy, etc..) and they all worked great when I tested the server using cURL. I am able to intercept the request headers and get the whitelisted URLs the user is authorized to use from the token and continue my logic from there.

However, as soon as I test it using my mobile device, the server is failing to get the basic64 token from the headers. For some reason it's always never there.

My question is, how do I successfully create a proxy server that authenticates users on a mobile device?

Code using http-proxy:

```
const http = require('http');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

const port = 8128;
const username = 'username';
const password = 'password';

const authBuffer = Buffer.from(username + ':' + password, 'ascii');
const authToken = 'Basic ' + authBuffer.toString('base64');

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => { 
  console.log("here")
  var authHeader = req.headers['proxy-authorization'];
  console.log(req.headers)

  if (authHeader === authToken) {
    console.log('[%s] [forward] %s', new Date, req.url);

  }
  else {
    console.error('[%s] [auth failed %s] %s', new Date, authHeader, req.url);
    res.statusCode = 404;
    res.end();
  }
});

server.timeout = 600000;

server.on('clientError', (err, socket) => {
  console.error('[%s] [error %s] %s', new Date, err.message);
  socket.end('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\n');
});

console.log("listening on port %d", port)
server.listen(port);
```